# Change footer in a joomla site through code and ftp

Tags: html, joomla, ftp

I have a friend who has a site made in Joomla by someone else. He asked me as favour to add to his site a facebook button at the footer of the website. He gave me ftp codes. The problem is I don't know where exactly to place the link with the image. I tried includes/footer.php and modules/mod_footer/mod_footer.php but nothing worked. In fact I cannot find the html code that I see when i right click on browser through "View source".
I don't want any solution through panel because the guy that created this site hasn't given my friend access like "Template Manager" etc.
I would like a hardcore solution please. The only thing I ask is where exactly I should place the code.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I didn't have access to Template Manager-> Edit HTML, I did the following, I went to the folder of the custom template and from there I downloaded index.php, and I managed from there to make my changes to footer just with code!

Comment: This obviously works fine but is not best practice as updating to the latest version of the template will overwrite your change.

Answer (score 2):

Joomla! is a database driven CMS.

The footer is usually a module being populated from the database, you won't be able to change it without `/administrator` access. Which your friend should already have if it's their website.

You can read about [Modules](http://docs.joomla.org/Module) on the [Joomla Doc's](http://docs.joomla.org/Module) website.

A possible approach (though not recommended as you're more likely to break the site than anything else) is to modify the template — you will find it in `/templates/template_name/`. Inside that directory will be lots of files and directories you could start by looking through that. You can [read about templates here](http://docs.joomla.org/Templates).

You may find the template is based on a framework in which case you will probably want to read up on the framework before you go modifying it, some of the popular ones are:

- [Gantry](http://www.gantry-framework.org) — http://www.gantry-framework.org
- [T3](http://t3-framework.org) — http://t3-framework.org
- [Warp](http://www.yootheme.com/themes/warp-framework) — http://www.yootheme.com/themes/warp-framework

Comment: Great start here! In my work with Joomla, I had a lot of success editing the template elements to customize my sites. Just be very careful with editing the PHP. It's very worthwhile to go through some tutorials about Joomla! framework basics before you really dig in to the code.

Comment: the problem is that the guy who created this site hasn't given html access to my friend through /administrator. That's why I need a hardcore solution...

Comment: Do you mean that your friend can't login via /administrator? In that case it's not his site and he should get his money back.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the website uses cPanel web hosting or similar, then the FTP password can be used to access cPanel and phpMyAdmin.

Assuming there is an existing footer module or similar, you can find and edit the module HTML in the content column in the jos_modules table.

With phpMyAdmin access, you could also reset the admin password and access the Joomla back-end normally to add or edit the footer.